# Python substring count code explanation

Tags: python

I was looking to write a program that counted the longest alphabetical substring in a string. e.g. str='abcdkjcd' would produce 'abcd' as the longest substring.

Using this site and some tutorials and function explanations, I found an answer that worked great, however I would really like to actually understand the code.
My limited understanding is that it joins each character to the variable if it is higher than the one it is currently looking at.

I annotated my code and was hoping somebody could explain 3 lines to me???

```
s='abc' # Sets a string value

def longeststr(str): # Defines the function to work out the longest substring
    longest=''  # Sets up a variable to store the longest value in with an empty string

    for i in range(len(str)): # Sets up the outside for loop to repeat the instructions below for the same amount of times as elements are in the string

        for j in range(i+1, len (str)): #For each element in the string started from the second element to the end, do the following...

            s=str[i:j+1] # Not sure??

            if ''.join(sorted(s)) == s: # If when try to join a sorted list of s is equal to s? Doesn't make sense??

                longest = max(longest, s, key = len)  # Not sure

            else:
                break # Exits the loop

    return 'Longest substring in alphabetical order is:' + longest # Returns value of longest string
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

s=str[i:j+1]  is a very pythony thing called a slice. Basically it's a substring from I to j+1 of str.

if ''.join(sorted(s)) == s.  If the string you at currently looking at is the same after being sorted alphabetically then it is in order

longest = max(longest, s, key = len). Longest is the max of either s or itself determined by the Len variable

Answer (score 0):

Variable `i` in the example points to position in source string.

Second loop, creates variable `j` that points to position next to position pointed by `i`.

`s=str[i:j+1]` - extracts substring from source string from position `i` to position `j`

`''.join(sorted(s))` sorts substring alphabetically. If sorted substring is equal to substring, then it means that substring is already alphabetical substring.

The following just selects whatever is bigger: value stored in `longest` variable or len of current substring.

```
longest = max(longest, s, key = len)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s='abc' # Sets a string value

def longeststr(str): # Defines the function to work out the longest substring, which accepts str as arg
    longest=''  # Sets up a variable to store the longest value in with an empty string

    for i in range(len(str)): # Sets up the first loop for i iterations from 0 to the lenght of the str (for i = 0;i<len(str);i++)
        for j in range(i+1, len (str)): #For each element next to the i-element 
            s=str[i:j+1] # slice string. eg str = 'abcd', i = 1, j=2, str[i:j+1] = 'bc'. for more information google 'python slice' So in this slice we start from fisrt and second literals, then from first and third, then ...., then from second and third and so on and on  

            if ''.join(sorted(s)) == s: # it is a little bit tricky.
```

if s = 'bca' then sorted(s) will give us 'abc' and s won't be equal to sorted(s). But if s = ' abc' then sorted(s) and s are equals and that is what we are looking for

```
                longest = max(longest, s, key = len)  # according to docs: returns the largest item in an iterable or the largest of two or more arguments. if key (possible options for list.sort() function) is specified, it is used like a criteria for max function. 

            else:
                break # Exits the loop

    return 'Longest substring in alphabetical order is:' + longest # Returns value of longest string
```